# Dynamic report parmeter

Tags: javascript, birt

This report had been working now but in params["select month"] i had given statically like jan 2012,feb 2012..etc so in Before open i wrote script by mentioning like `selectedDate = new Date(2012,params["select month"] - 1, 1);`...now its possible to change it by dynamically ...if year change the `params["select month"]`have to change how to do that kindly some one can help on this??

```
mysql:
    SELECT
    YEAR (CLASSICMODELS.PAYMENTS.PAYMENTDATE) AS YEARNUMBER,
    MONTH (CLASSICMODELS.PAYMENTS.PAYMENTDATE) AS MONNUMBER,
    SUM (CLASSICMODELS.PAYMENTS.AMOUNT) AS MONTOTAL
    FROM 
    CLASSICMODELS.PAYMENTS
    WHERE 
    (YEAR(CLASSICMODELS.PAYMENTS.PAYMENTDATE) = p11
    AND MONTH(CLASSICMODELS.PAYMENTS.PAYMENTDATE) = p12)
    OR
    (YEAR(CLASSICMODELS.PAYMENTS.PAYMENTDATE) = p21
    AND MONTH(CLASSICMODELS.PAYMENTS.PAYMENTDATE) = p22)
    GROUP BY 
    YEAR (CLASSICMODELS.PAYMENTS.PAYMENTDATE),
    MONTH (CLASSICMODELS.PAYMENTS.PAYMENTDATE)
    ORDER BY 1,2
```

In dataset Before open method:

```
selectedDate = new Date(2012,params["select month"] - 1, 1);
if(params["period"] == "last month")
{
    pastDate = new Date(2012,params["select month"] - 2, 1);
}
else
{
    pastDate = new Date(2011,params["select month"] - 1, 1);
}

this.queryText = this.queryText.replace("p11","2012");
this.queryText = this.queryText.replace("p12",params["select month"].toString());
this.queryText = this.queryText.replace("p21",BirtDateTime.year(pastDate).toString());
this.queryText = this.queryText.replace("p22",BirtDateTime.month(pastDate).toString());
```

Comment: So if "period" is "last month" you want the query to return the data for the selected month in 2012 and the month before that, and otherwise you want the query to return the data for the selected month in 2012 and the selected month in 2011. But what exactly is your question?

Comment: yes if "period" is "last month" i want to return data for Perivous MOnth of params["select month"] selected and if "period" is "last Year" i want to return data for Perivous year of params["select month"] selected  for example if i select a parameter params["select month"] is jan 2012 and period like "last month" i want the query return for  pervious month of i.e dec 2011 like wise for year also

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't do something like if(params["select month"] == 0) { pastDate = new Date(2012 - 1, 11, 1) } else {... the stuff you have ...} ?

General note: don't use spaces in your variable names.

Comment: if i do it cant be access year dynamically